# Create verification if user is the site owner

Tags: drupal, verification, ownership

I am using Drupal 7 and have a content type. Simple registered users can fill out just two fields of this content type (for example, the name of the website.)  But the owner of the website can also fill out the type.

I need a way for the owner of website could confirm that it is indeed his website. After doing so, more fields should become available for him. Google, Piniterest, etc. do something similar.

How can I create such a verification process? Are there some ready-made solutions, modules or anything that can implement some part of this task? Can somebody share some code or supply instructions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems these might help you, depending on how you want to retrieve the user's role.

http://snipplr.com/view/12430/

or

[Drupal Conditional PHP if admin or user has certain role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324506/drupal-conditional-php-if-admin-or-user-has-certain-role)

Good luck

Comment: I guess I should create a user role called 'site owner'.
But still I need to verify that the user is the site owner?
I guess it should be system like in google when site owner add the website for verification .
But I need the help with the code.